# Why width is different?

Tags: html, css

Can't understand why,despite having the same `width:450px` and `margin:0 auto`, `width` of `.menu` and `width` of `.blog` is different. See my code:

```css
body {
  border-top:4px solid #F55D2D;
  background: white;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: 'Mako', sans-serif;
}

header {
  width:450px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.menu {
  width:450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:green;
}

.menu li {
  display:inline;
  padding:5px 15px;
  
}

.blog {
  width: 450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:green;
}

.post {
  /*border: 1px solid grey;*/
  margin: 20px auto;
  
  height:125px;
  padding:0 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  color:black;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
  position:relative;
}

.post::after {
  background:url(Photos/intro3cropped.jpg);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">XYZ EVENTS</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuAll">ALL EVENTS</li>
      <li class="menuConcert">CONCERTS</li>
      <li class="menuTheatre">THEATRE</li>
      <li class="menuFestival">FESTIVALS</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="blog">
    <div class="post concert">
      <h4>Concert 1</h4>
      <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
      <p>When: XYZ h</p>
      <small>(Click to expand)</small>
      <p class="descr">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
    </div>
```

Why `.blog` is thinner than `.menu`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your menu is a list item and list items have default padding applied. See the example below for the same code but with the padding on the `ul` element removed.

```css
body {
  border-top:4px solid #F55D2D;
  background: white;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: 'Mako', sans-serif;
}

header {
  width:450px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.menu {
  width:450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:green;
  padding:0;
}

.menu li {
  display:inline;
  padding:5px 15px;
  
}

.blog {
  width: 450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:green;
}

.post {
  /*border: 1px solid grey;*/
  margin: 20px auto;
  
  height:125px;
  padding:0 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  color:black;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
  position:relative;
}

.post::after {
  background:url(Photos/intro3cropped.jpg);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">XYZ EVENTS</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuAll">ALL EVENTS</li>
      <li class="menuConcert">CONCERTS</li>
      <li class="menuTheatre">THEATRE</li>
      <li class="menuFestival">FESTIVALS</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="blog">
    <div class="post concert">
      <h4>Concert 1</h4>
      <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
      <p>When: XYZ h</p>
      <small>(Click to expand)</small>
      <p class="descr">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
    </div>
```

Another option is to set `box-sizing:border-box;` on the `ul` element instead of removing the padding.

```css
body {
  border-top:4px solid #F55D2D;
  background: white;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family: 'Mako', sans-serif;
}

header {
  width:450px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.menu {
  width:450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:green;
  box-sizing:border-box;;
}

.menu li {
  display:inline;
  padding:5px 15px;
  
}

.blog {
  width: 450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:green;
}

.post {
  /*border: 1px solid grey;*/
  margin: 20px auto;
  
  height:125px;
  padding:0 10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  color:black;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
  position:relative;
}

.post::after {
  background:url(Photos/intro3cropped.jpg);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">XYZ EVENTS</h1>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuAll">ALL EVENTS</li>
      <li class="menuConcert">CONCERTS</li>
      <li class="menuTheatre">THEATRE</li>
      <li class="menuFestival">FESTIVALS</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="blog">
    <div class="post concert">
      <h4>Concert 1</h4>
      <p>Where: XYZ Arena</p>
      <p>When: XYZ h</p>
      <small>(Click to expand)</small>
      <p class="descr">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the menu element is an `ul` and by default, it has a padding, in webkit browser for example, the following styles are applied:

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

and since the padding is part of the width, just add `padding: 0` to `.menu`, that's one of the reasons why people use `normalize.css` or `reset.css.`

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yes, this is aligned with the answer above. The funny thing is that I am using normalize css. Not sure why yet but I will learn soon I guess. In any case, if normalize is supposed to fix this kind of things, seems it didn't work for me

Comment: @perettxintxola normalize don't reset everything to 0 like reset.css do, they keep some browser specific styles, like this one ;)